# gmap macro doesn´t parse.. why?

Tags: nodes, google-maps

I have in my contact form something like

[gmap markers=big red::40.26041912699509,-3.8385844230651855 |zoom=15 |center=40.26217119406393,-3.840494155883789 |width=300px |height=200px |control=Small |type=Map]

but it doesn´t parse when I put it into the body of a content type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an input filter that uses the GMAP filter before it can work : Go to Administer > Site Configuration > Input format > Add Input Format and select the gmap filter in the filters list

Comment: and how can you construct the coordinates? i've tried to copy the link from gmaps... but it points somewhere else,

Comment: ok I found this tool http://gmap.chicagotech.org/map/macro